# CMakes can't find boost (and most anything else) on Windows

Tags: windows, boost, cmake

So I've got boost installed in C:\Program Files\boost_1_47_0\, with the library files in ./stage/lib/ and include files in ./boost/*

So I set an environment variable, BOOST_ROOT to C:\Program Files\boost_1_47_0 and run cmake on my project.  I get errors that it can't find the requested boost libraries (math_c99, program_options, unit_test_framework).

This is odd, since I have the .lib files for all of them in BOOST_ROOT\stage\lib, and the include files are all there too.

I even added a SET(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ... according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost) but still no luck.  Any idea what gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the line

```
SET(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.47" "1.47.0")
```

before calling `find_package`.

Comment: Arg, our CMakeList file only had it up to version 1.45... now on to Armadillo, probably a similar thing.