# making boost work with cmake ( fatal error: boost/smart_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory )

Tags: c++, qt, boost, opencv

After digging for hours on this, I finally need some expert help.
I am new to cmake and trying to port my Visual Studio 2008 project to cmake.
My project uses opencv, qt and boost libraries. 
Now I have managed to run simple cmake examples with opencv and qt but I am stuck with boost.

The bottleneck is this:  CMake finds the correct boost version, finds the libraries and gives no error while configuration.
But when I try to build the project using make, it gives me:

> " fatal error: boost/smart_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory"

Assuming the configuration is done right, cmake should be able to find the boost include directories.
I have set `BOOST_ROOT` to the correct boost root directory and that's why configuration does not give errors. But what happens while running make? Am I missing something simple here? Need help desperately...
I am sorry if this is a stupid question.

Here's my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )

project (CMakeBoostTutorial)

find_package( Boost 1.46.1 COMPONENTS date_time REQUIRED)

link_directories ( ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

include_directories ( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable ( helloworld helloworld.cc )

target_link_libraries (
    helloworld
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

And here's my helloworld.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;<br/>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cout<<"Hello World";
  return 0;
}
```

PS: This compiles and runs fine if I remove the `#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>` line

Comment: EDIT: I also found it works if I hard code the path to my boost installation in the CMakeLists.txt file as 'include_directories("/path/to/boost/installation")' But that's a great hit to the portability of my project which I can't take. This also means that cmake is not setting the variable BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS somehow. I wonder why?

Comment: SOLVED:!!! Well this was a very silly thing! In my CMakeLists.txt, the line was 'include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})' instead of 'include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})' ! I did not know that that part was case sensitive! I am no longer getting this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cmake doesn't find Boost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost)