# CMake Error: Unable to find requested Boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to install a particular c++ library that has Boost dependencies. I installed Boost no problem and the include path is under /usr/local/include/.

However, when I call cmake, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at     
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1245 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
Boost version: 0.0.0
Boost include path: /usr/include
Detected version of Boost is too old.  Requested version was 1.36 (or newer).
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:10 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

I know the Boost include path does not match, but I don't know how to have it reference the correct path. The CMakeLists.txt file calls FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.36 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED): I didn't see any parameters that would allow me to specify the path.

Thanks,

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Boost path with:

```
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "/.../boost")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "/.../boost/lib")
```

Making sure to place this before the FIND_PACKAGE call in CMakeLists.txt.
([Cmake doesn't find Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost))