# How to fix the error when I compile the solidity?

Tags: cmake, ethereum, contract, cmake-gui, solidity

There is the error log when I install the solidity to compile my ethereum contract:

```
  "CMake" Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the "
CMake" files:
 /home/solidity/libdevcore/Boost_INCLUDE_DIR
used as include directory in directory /home/solidity/libdevcore
/home/solidity/libevmasm/Boost_INCLUDE_DIR
used as include directory in directory /home/solidity/libevmasm
/home/solidity/libsolidity/Boost_INCLUDE_DIR
used as include directory in directory /home/solidity/libsolidity
/home/solidity/solc/Boost_INCLUDE_DIR
used as include directory in directory /home/solidity/solc
/home/solidity/test/Boost_INCLUDE_DIR
used as include directory in directory /home/solidity/test
```

How to fix these errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cmake doesn't find Boost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost)

Comment: no, It did not fix my problem. and any other solutions?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. See also: [ask]

Comment: okay,  There is no the configuration which it sayed  in CMakeLists.txt.
like "Boost_COMPILER " or the following.
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
ENDIF()

Comment: @mike: These explanations should be **in the question post**, not in the comments.