# CMake found and NOT found boost simultaneously

Tags: boost, cmake

I am trying to install [ismrmrd](http://ismrmrd.github.io/) and following the installation guide for Windows.

In the step `cmake-gui.exe` my cmake is not finding installed Boost.

After adding [those lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3813010/5161420) to `CMakeLists.txt` the result became interesting.

[image: CMake error screen shot]

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE 8/21

thanks [vre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5251059/vre) and [user1234567](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2799037/usr1234567)

Now I changed to boost 1.66 and still no luck.

The new screenshot shows FindBoost is not complain anything now.
But still not any boost found.
[image: new screenshot]

---

UPDATE 8/22

After adding

`cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)`

and

`set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON) find_package(Boost REQUIRED system filesystem) include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})` `target_link_libraries(ismrmrd ${Boost_LIBRARIES})` into `CMakeLists.txt` by the suggestion from [vre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5251059/vre)

The resulting error became this screenshot
[image]

Comment: You might need to add a variable to your CMakeLists.txt `set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 1.68.0 1.68)` as your CMake release date is older than the release date of your Boost version. FindBoost.cmake only knows Boost versions before its release date not newer ones.

Comment: For Boost 1.68 you need the lastest CMake master. For your CMake version, 1.67 or older should work. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124857/2799037

Comment: Did you build boost yourself or used a prebuilt version from this site `https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/` ? They are the maintainers of BOOST and provide binaries for lots of MSVC compilers. To correctly use Boost static libraries you should add `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system filesystem)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
` and to link against it `target_link_libraries(your_target ${Boost_LIBRARIES})` to your CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: [@vre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5251059/vre) I do download prebuilt version from sourceforge, but I ran `bootstrap.bat` and `b2.exe variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static address-model=64` from [link](https://github.com/cryptonotefoundation/cryptonote/issues/119#issuecomment-403515821)

Comment: You are rebuilding boost. But that's not needed if you use the prebuilt package from the sourceforge adress mentioned above. It comes with dynamic and static libraries, release and debug mode built for the named compiler. All that is needed is to reference it correctly in the CMakeLists.txt. What compiler are you using?

Comment: I think it's using my installed `VC++ 2017 version 15.8 v14.15 latest v141 tools`, so i have a line `set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:/local/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.1")` in `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: So you should download and install https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.66.0/boost_1_66_0-msvc-14.1-64.exe to "C:/local/boost_1_66_0" and add a variable BOOST_ROOT to your CMakeLists.txt file before setting the other variables I mentioned in a previous post, e.g. `set(BOOST_ROOT C:/local/boost_1_66_0)`. Be sure to delete the CMakeCache.txt file from the build directory, because results of a previous run may not be overwritten otherwise. I always recommend this procedure to get your CMakeLists.txt working first, later you can figure out how to build Boost by yourself.

Comment: Can you share your CMakeLists.txt? It's easier to recommend some changes by viewing the script than to guess the missing pieces from the error messages.

Comment: @vre The  CMakeLists.txt is a modified version from [ismrmrd](https://github.com/ismrmrd/ismrmrd/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) every single addition is noted in the main ask body. A copy is [here](https://jpst.it/1mCKN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is to long for comments I try to come up with a recipe:

The commands needed for using Boost header only/static libraries are:

```
set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 1.66.0 1.66)
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/local/boost_1_66_0")
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
```

For using solely header only libraries use

```
find_package(Boost)
```

otherwise name the components (libraries) to be used after the COMPONENTS keyword and use

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS <e.g. filesystem system ...>)

if (Boost_FOUND)
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  add_definitions( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
endif()
```

Later you reference the imported targets (libraries) for header only Boost in a call

```
target_link_libraries(yourproject Boost::boost)
```

or for named library components in a call

```
target_link_libraries(yourproject ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Be sure to always delete the CMakeCache.txt file in the build directory when making changes to the CMakeLists.txt regarding Boost and Boost components, as it might cache the values of a previous CMake run.