# Finding boost-python3 with Anaconda cmake prefix

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, anaconda, caffe

**DLDR** How do I point the cmake at boost-python3 library? It is not automatically detected by cmake.

---

I'm trying to build [caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) for Python 3.6 using the provided cmake.

My system specs:

- Python 3.6.5, Anaconda custom (64-bit)
- Mac OS 10.13.6
- No CUDA

I've installing boost with brew, e.g.

```
brew install boost boost-python3
```

I can see the boost libraries using `find / -name libboost* 2>/dev/null`. They occur in three directories

1. `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib/`
2. `/usr/local/lib/` -> symlink to above
3. boost-python3 is in `/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.67.0/lib/`

If I run `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<anaconda_env_path> -D python_version=3`, I get this at the top of the output

```
-- Boost version: 1.67.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   filesystem
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
```

But further down, I also get

```
CMake Warning at /Users/Mauceri/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1723 (message):
  No header defined for python-py365; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:157 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (include)


-- Could NOT find Boost
CMake Warning at /Users/Mauceri/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1723 (message):
  No header defined for python-py36; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:164 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (include)


-- Could NOT find Boost
CMake Warning at /Users/Mauceri/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1723 (message):
  No header defined for python-py3; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:164 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (include)

-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Python interface is disabled or not all required dependencies found. Building without it...
```

Similar to [Cmake doesn't find Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost), I have tried adding

```
-DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib/ -DBoost_DEBUG=1
```

to the cmake command. In the resulting output, the following repeats three times with boost_python-py365, boost_python-py36, boost_python-py3, and boost_python:

```
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1121 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1123 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1125 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = 
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1127 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1129 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1131 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1199 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1201 ]   BOOST_ROOT = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/include/
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1203 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = 
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1205 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1207 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1306 ] location of version.hpp: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/include/boost/version.hpp
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1330 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.67.0
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1416 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = 
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1426 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1502 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1504 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1567 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG   = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1756 ] Searching for PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_python-mt-1_67;boost_python-mt;boost_python
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:400 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] Searching for PYTHON_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_python-mt-d-1_67;boost_python-mt-d;boost_python-mt;boost_python
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:400 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
[ /Users/me/anaconda/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1883 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
Could NOT find Boost
Boost version: 1.67.0
Boost include path: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/include
Could not find the following Boost libraries:
        boost_python
No Boost libraries were found. You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.
```

Therefore, I think the boost-python path is what is missing. I also tried adding `-DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR`, but that didn't seem to change anything.

The [FindBoost documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) contains this comment about boost-python

> Note that Boost Python components require a Python version suffix
>   (Boost 1.67 and later), e.g. python36 or python27 for the versions
>   built against Python 3.6 and 2.7, respectively. This also applies to
>   additional components using Python including mpi_python and numpy.
>   Earlier Boost releases may use distribution-specific suffixes such as
>   2, 3 or 2.7. These may also be used as suffixes, but note that they
>   are not portable.

I noticed that the boost-python3 libraries had the suffix 37 (libboost_python37.a), so I also tried using an anaconda environment with python 3.7, but the same errors persisted.

How can I get my cmake to find the boost-python3 libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CMake 3.12 FindPython2 and FindPython3 were introduced. That reworked the whole handling of finding Python and also improved the support for Anaconda.

As you are using Boost 1.67, I would advice you to switch to CMake 3.12 or newer anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124857/2799037

If possible, use the newest CMake version available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Look what files boost-python package brings.

```
brew ls --verbose boost-python3
```

Among them there should be `boost-pythonXX-config.cmake` file or something like this. Problem could be in version. For `find_package` use correct package name corresponding to this filename.