# cmake FindBoost not finding Boost libraries when building with MinGW on Windows

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

`qtcreator` supports both `qmake` and `cmake` for cross platform development and
`qmake` works fine for both `msvc` and `MinGW` builds on `Windows`. However, I'd prefer to support just one tool: `cmake`.

The `CMakeLists.txt` at [via-httplib](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib) works fine on `linux` and when using `cmake` to build `msvc` on `Windows`. 
However, when using `cmake` to build `MinGW` on `Windows`, I get the following error:

> CMake Error at C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2100 (message):
>   Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Boost version: 1.69.0
>
> Boost include path: D:/DevLibraries/boost/boost_1_69_0
>
> Could not find the following Boost libraries:
>
> ```
>       boost_system
> ```
>
> No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR
>   to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the
>   location of Boost.

Both the `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` and `BOOST_ROOT` environment variables are set and are found when using the `Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64` generator and default native compilers

The error message indicates that when using the `MinGW Makefiles` and default native compilers, `cmake` finds the `BOOST_ROOT` environment variable but not `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`. So it does not seem to be the same problem described here: [Cmake doesn't find Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost)

Is this a bug in `FindBoost.cmake`? Is there a "work around"?

Comment: As far as I remember, Boost installation, suitable for Virtual Studio, cannot be used for MinGW building. In any case, you may enable `Boost_DEBUG` option (via `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` if you run `cmake` from the command line) and check what actually goes wrong.

Answer (score 6):

It is an issue with the `_boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG` in `FindBoost.cmake`, described on line 1518.
The tag was added to handle Boost 1.66.0 and later versions.

It is not setting the `_boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG` for `MinGW` to `-x64`, so it is searching for boost library names like:

```
libboost_system-mgw73-mt-d-1_69.a
```

instead of:

```
libboost_system-mgw73-mt-d-x64-1_69.a
```

There is a workaround: set the `cmake` variable: `Boost_ARCHITECTURE` to `-x64`.

Note: setting `Boost_ARCHITECTURE` as an environment variable does not work, as `FindBoost.cmake` does not read `Boost_ARCHITECTURE` as an environment variable.

Comment: Related cmake [issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17575) for problems with finding boost libraries with names containing architecture tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really unblocked me!