# \mingw-w64\ ... \ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_filesystem

Tags: c++, windows, boost, mingw, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile simple c++ program with mingw on "windows 7 64bit" command prompt. Error I get is:

```
>gcc fs.cpp -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
c:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_filesystem
c:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Maybe useful system variable information:

```
c:\Boost\lib>echo %path%
C:\Boost\boost-build\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;c:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\;c:\Boost\lib\

c:\Boost\lib>echo %library_path%
c:\Boost\lib

c:\Boost\lib>echo %cplus_include_path%
c:\Boost\include\
```

and a content of boost/lib is:

```
c:\Boost\lib>dir
 Volume in drive C is Acer
 Volume Serial Number is 62C5-4B7E

 Directory of c:\Boost\lib

13.06.2019.  00:31    <DIR>          .
13.06.2019.  00:31    <DIR>          ..
13.06.2019.  00:28         5.608.426 libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-d-x32-1_70
13.06.2019.  00:28         6.553.512 libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-d-x64-1_70
13.06.2019.  00:28         3.713.979 libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-d-x64-1_70
13.06.2019.  00:28            92.342 libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-d-x64-1_70
13.06.2019.  00:28           344.104 libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-s-x32-1_70
13.06.2019.  00:28           405.348 libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-s-x64-1_70
13.06.2019.  00:28         5.608.426 libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-sd-x32-1_7
13.06.2019.  00:28         6.553.512 libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-sd-x64-1_7
13.06.2019.  00:28           344.104 libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-x32-1_70.a
13.06.2019.  00:28           405.348 libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70.a
13.06.2019.  00:28           239.395 libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70.d
13.06.2019.  00:28            92.132 libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70.d
13.06.2019.  00:28             2.822 libboost_system-mgw81-mt-d-x32-1_70.a
13.06.2019.  00:28             3.118 libboost_system-mgw81-mt-d-x64-1_70.a
13.06.2019.  00:28            49.550 libboost_system-mgw81-mt-d-x64-1_70.dll
13.06.2019.  00:28             1.772 libboost_system-mgw81-mt-d-x64-1_70.dll
13.06.2019.  00:28               730 libboost_system-mgw81-mt-s-x32-1_70.a
13.06.2019.  00:28               924 libboost_system-mgw81-mt-s-x64-1_70.a
13.06.2019.  00:28             2.822 libboost_system-mgw81-mt-sd-x32-1_70.a
13.06.2019.  00:28             3.118 libboost_system-mgw81-mt-sd-x64-1_70.a
13.06.2019.  00:28               730 libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x32-1_70.a
13.06.2019.  00:28               924 libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70.a
13.06.2019.  00:28            47.834 libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70.dll
13.06.2019.  00:28             1.760 libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70.dll.a
```

I've tried to include path manually with

```
gcc fs.cpp -o fs.exe -Lc:\Boost\lib -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

or with

```
gcc fs.cpp -o fs.exe -L c:\Boost\lib -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

or with

```
gcc fs.cpp -o fs.exe -L c:\Boost\lib -llibboost_filesystem -llibboost_system
```

and gotthe same output.

To me it looks like a linker problem. But, I'm not experienced. Could this be a product of badly compiled library files?

What options should I use when compiling c++ on Windows? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is caused by the complicated naming scheme of `boost` library files,
see [Boost Getting Started on Windows: library naming](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming).

In short, `boost` appends characters to library file names to specify (amongst other things):

- compiler version: `-mgw81`,
- multi-threading: `-mt`,
- machine architecture and address model: `-x64`
- and boost version: `-1_70`.

Therefore, `boost_filesystem` becomes: `boost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70` and `boost_system` becomes: `boost_system-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70`, so try:

```
gcc fs.cpp -o fs.exe -Lc:\Boost\lib -lboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70 -lboost_system-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70
```

Note: build systems like [cmake](https://cmake.org/) simplify these issues, but they can introduce new ones, see: [cmake FindBoost not finding Boost libraries when building with MinGW on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943885/cmake-findboost-not-finding-boost-libraries-when-building-with-mingw-on-windows).

Comment: wow, first answer and it worked! :-) Thank you. I was ignorant. I thought linker knows which one to pick for me. I was spoiled by Debian (my daily driver) which installed only "the right version":