# Boost with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, boost, qt-creator

I was trying to use boost/filesystem in my C++ project made with QtCreator.
The problem was that when building, I got the following error:

```
"error: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'"
```

To use boost, I had performed the following actions:

- download boost library boost_1_73_0.7z file
- unzip it in my computer (under D:\Development\Boost)
- in .pro file, I have added the following option

  INCLUDEPATH += D:/Development/Boost
- in my .cpp file, I have added the following include

  #include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
- At this point, when compiling, I had the following error in Qt creator IDE

  "error: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'"

The root cause is the following : FileSystem needs to be built. Therefore, I have built this boost library by :

- adding gcc and g++ to the path variable (it is succesful as I could call 'g++' and 'gcc' from the command prompt).
- opening Qt command prompt (I used Qt 5.15.0 (MinGW 73.0 64-bit) ) and by navigating to the repository where boost is installed.

[image]

- executing the following command in the command prompt in the directory (D:\Development\Boost): **bootstrap gcc**

[image]

- executing the following command in the command prompt in the directory where I had unzipped Boost: **b2 toolset=gcc link=shared threading=multi --build-type=complete stage**. This action has created a the directory **D:\develoment\Boost\Stage\lib** with all the dll, including 'libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_73.dll'.
- Now it's time to link the library in Qt creator. I have thus added the following in my .pro file:

  LIBS += -LD:/Development/Boost/stage/lib libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_73

When compiling, the error is gone.

Thanks for your help.
Gatien

Comment: Did you build boost? Although boost contains header only libraries it does also contain libraries that need to be compiled.

Comment: This should help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265879/how-do-i-build-boost-1-55-with-mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265879/how-do-i-build-boost-1-55-with-mingw) Note to build the current version not 1.55 that is many years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @drescherjm commented, you need to build the `boost` libraries.
They are **not** in the `D:/Development/Boost/libs` directory.

You appear to be using Windows and have `boost` installed on your "D:" drive.
I assume your using the `MinGw` compiler that comes with `Qt Creator`, not Visual Studio.

To build `boost` with `MinGw`, first open the relevant Qt Command prompt, e.g. `Qt 5.12.3 (MinGW 7.3.0 64-bit)` and type the following:

```
D:
cd \Development\Boost
bootstrap.bat gcc
b2 toolset=gcc link=shared threading=multi --build-type=complete stage
```

This will build the MinGw `boost` libraries in your directory: `D:\Development\Boost\stage\lib`.
Then change the link command to:

```
LIBS += -LD:/Development/Boost/stage/lib -l boost_system-mgw73-mt-x64-d-1_66
```

Note: the precise name of the `boost_system` library depends upon how `boost` named it in your version.
See [Boost Getting Started on Windows: library naming.](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming)  the answer here: [mingw-w64 cannot find -lboost_filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571745/mingw-w64-ld-exe-cannot-find-lboost-filesystem/56575129#56575129) and the filenames you built in the `D:\Development\Boost\stage\lib` directory.

Comment: You updated your question while I posted my answer, amazing timing!  You only built `boost-filesystem`, you also need to build `boost-system`.

Comment: So are my step ok so far? in the meantime, I have undo everything and follow exactly your steps. I'll see what it brings. I do not mind doing the undo-do-undo-do loop until it works :-D

Comment: it does not work. In Qt creator, I got: "error: cannot find -lboost_system-mgw73-mt-x64-d-1_73"

Comment: Yes, your steps are ok so far, And, no don't undo everything, just build `boost-system`: b2 toolset=gcc system and then try to link your program.

Comment: I have built 'system' and added ''LIBS += -LD:/Development/Boost/stage/lib -l boost_system-mgw73-mt-x64-d-1_73". Now the error is "error: cannot find -lboost_system-mgw73-mt-x64-d-1_73". Any thought?

Comment: Yes, read the last paragraph of my answer and think it through!

Comment: I think that I begin to understand : b2 creates dlls and I should refer to those files in the .pro file. So when looking in the stage/lib directory, I found all those dll there. Before, stage/lib was not there. I have added "LIBS += -LD:/Development/Boost/stage/lib libboost_system-mgw8-mt-x64-1_73", but now I have the same error (error: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()). What did I miss this time?

Comment: The problem is gone by simply reediting the cpp calling FileSystem... thanks and sorry for upsetting you.