# Keep receiving "CMake Error: Could NOT find Boost" yet it did find it

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, jetbrains-ide

Cloned a repository and installed the Boost library. My IDE (CLion) keeps telling me

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2021.3/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: regex date_time system filesystem
  unit_test_framework program_options) (found version "1.67.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2021.3/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2021.3/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2345 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:29 (find_package)
```

Prior to this, I was trying to use the most updated Boost library which led me to more errors, after changing it to the correct library, those errors went away, leaving me with this. This error also remains when trying to use the new library too.

I have tried `set(BOOST_ROOT C:/local/boost_1_71_0)` as was the correct answer on another similar post, yet it didn't work. I have also tried adding it to my path, which also does nothing. To note: It is strange because it says the version number of the Boost library yet it says could not be found.

I am using CLion's bundled CMake, but I also have the official CMake installed just in case. I don't think CLion's cmake is the issue.

Comment: It said it found version 1.67 but could not find the required libraries. What version of boost do you have installed? Is that version the correct version for your compiler and does it match the 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: You may want to do what this answer says to debug the search for boost: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/8770217/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8770217/487892)

Comment: @drescherjm I have installed Boost 1.67.0. I installed this because a tutorial I'm following said to use this one specifically. My CMake is the default CLion bundle, the rest of the toolchain is MSYS CLang. I have pasted that line of code into the CMakeList.txt but I'm not sure what to do with the debug information, it just shows me where it's looking for the missing file.